Problem Deriving "The General Uncertainty Principle" in Section 5.7 of Susskind's "Quantum Mechanics"
I'm having a problem in section 5.7 of Susskind's "Quantum Mechanics, The Theoretical Minimum".  Specifically, I'm trying to derive eq. 5.11,
$$
2\sqrt{ \langle \mathbf{A}^2 \rangle \langle \mathbf{B}^2 \rangle}
= |\langle \psi | \mathbf{AB} | \psi \rangle
- \langle \psi | \mathbf{BA} | \psi \rangle | \tag{5.11}
$$
where $\mathbf{A}$ and $\mathbf{B}$ and observables (and, hence, Hermitian), by following the text and substituting eqs. 5.10,
$$
| X \rangle = \mathbf{A} | \psi \rangle \\
| Y \rangle = i\mathbf{B} | \psi \rangle \tag{5.10}
$$
into the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, eq. 5.9,
$$
2|X||Y| \ge | \langle X | Y \rangle + \langle Y | X \rangle | \tag{5.9}
$$
But I'm having a problem.
I can derive the left side of eq. 5.9 using,
$$
|X| = \sqrt{ \langle X | X \rangle }\\
= \sqrt{\langle \psi | \mathbf{A}^\dagger \mathbf{A} | \psi \rangle }\\
= \sqrt{\langle \psi | \mathbf{A} \mathbf{A} | \psi \rangle} \\
= \sqrt{\langle \psi | \mathbf{A}^2 | \psi \rangle} \\
= \sqrt{\langle \mathbf{A}^2 \rangle}
$$
And,
$$|Y|  = \sqrt{\langle Y | Y \rangle} \\
= \sqrt{\langle \psi | -i \mathbf{B}^\dagger i \mathbf{B} | \psi \rangle} \\
= \sqrt{\langle \psi | -i^2 \mathbf{B} \mathbf{B} | \psi \rangle} \\
= \sqrt{\langle \psi | \mathbf{B}^2 | \psi \rangle} \\
= \sqrt{\langle \mathbf{B}^2 \rangle}
$$
So,
$$2|X||Y| = 2\sqrt{\langle  \mathbf{A}^2 \rangle} \sqrt{\langle \mathbf{B}^2 \rangle}
=  2\sqrt{\langle \mathbf{A}^2 \rangle \langle \mathbf{B}^2 \rangle}
$$
So far so good.
But when I try to derive the right side of eq. 5.9 I end out with an extra $i$.  Using,
$$
\langle X | Y \rangle = \langle \psi | \mathbf{A}^\dagger i \mathbf{B} | \psi \rangle \\
= \langle \psi | i \mathbf{AB} | \psi \rangle \\
= i \langle \psi | \mathbf{AB} | \psi \rangle
$$
And,
$$\langle Y | X \rangle = \langle \psi | -i \mathbf{B}^\dagger \mathbf{A} | \psi \rangle \\
= \langle \psi | -i \mathbf{BA} | \psi \rangle \\
= -i \langle \psi | \mathbf{BA} | \psi \rangle
$$
Which means,
$$
| \langle X | Y \rangle + \langle Y | X \rangle | = | i \langle \psi | \mathbf{AB} | \psi \rangle
-i \langle \psi | \mathbf{BA} | \psi \rangle |
$$
Which is almost the same as eq. 5.11, but I've got extra $i$'s on the right hand side.  What am I doing wrong?

You are correct, but there's one last simplifying step. The norm of the product is the product of the norms. For two complex numbers, $z_1$ and $z_2$:
\begin{equation}
|z_1\cdot z_2| = |z_1|\cdot|z_2|
\end{equation}
So the right hand side of your last equation is
\begin{align}
|i\langle\psi|\mathbf{AB}|\psi\rangle - i\langle\psi|\bf{BA}|\psi\rangle| &= |i(\langle\psi|\mathbf{AB}|\psi\rangle - \langle\psi|\mathbf{BA}|\psi\rangle)| \\
&=|i|\cdot|\langle\psi|\bf{AB}|\psi\rangle - \langle\psi|\bf{BA}|\psi\rangle| \\
&= |\langle\psi|\bf{AB}|\psi\rangle - \langle\psi|\bf{BA}|\psi\rangle|
\end{align}
which is the desired equation.
